# Is the `user-event` library compatible with React Native Testing Library?

Tags: react-native-testing-library, user-event

Can anyone confirm whether the `user-event` library is compatible with React Native Testing Library?

I'm guessing not, as the `user-event` [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro) say

> the library can be used with any framework as long as there is a DOM

and the React Native Testing Library [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-native-testing-library/intro) say

> does not run in a browser environment...unlike other wrappers that use DOM Testing Library as the base.

and also that they use `fireEvent` in all their examples in the docs.

But I don't know much about the internals of how Native apps actually run, so I don't know whether there *is* actually some sort of DOM that `user-event` could use.

Would love confirmation from someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an equivalent User Event API has been added to React Native Testing Library itself, in [version 12.2.0](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/releases/tag/v12.2.0) and is in beta (as of Aug 2023) -

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/user-event